# UIViewController presented without background

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift5, presentviewcontroller

When im present new VC background is clear and I can see previous VC.

Second VC is empty (without any view)

How FIX?

```
let vc = AddScrollVC()
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
present(navController, animated: true)
```

[image]

> Second VC is presented, shown only button in navBar

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue with replacing this code

```
let VC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PresentVC") as! PresentVC
VC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: If I not use storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this, This is work fine for me

```
let VC = PresentVC()
VC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Still have the problem, which swift version and Xcode version are you using

Comment: Xcode 13.2.1, Swift 5

Comment: let VC = SplashScreen()
VC.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
present(VC, animated: true) I use this code for present I don't face any problem do you give any color for your presenting VC if not then check and give it a color

Comment: If still you have the problem feel free to contact me. My whats app number is (8547160914)